# Looping over independent variables in a regression to store P values and R squared values

Tags: r

I'm trying to run 150 multiple regression models with the same dependent variable (grain yield) and a covariate (age), but a different predictor in every instance. I would like to store R-squared values and P values for the results of each regression in a data frame that I can easily look at to see which hypotheses are supported by the data. I'm open to alternate ways of doing this- basically I want to know which of the 150 potential predictors have significant interaction with age by glancing at a table, and it would also be nice to know which of the 150 predictors are significant on their own. I've looked through dozens of answers on SO, but I'm still not sure what the best approach is. I do understand that running so many models will lead to Type I error inflation. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5henzs8o83rvikj/grain%20yield%20by%20environment%20long.csv?dl=0) is a link to my data, but feel free to present a solution in a mtcars or iris if you'd prefer. So far, I've tried using lapply and sapply and writing a function, using a for loop, using tidyr, using list in a for loop, and using append in a for loop. Here's the solution using lapply and sapply, which is promising, but the output is not something that I can present to show which predictors are significant or not- I still have to call out each result one by one. The code takes forever to run, which is why I'm restricting it to the first four columns. All the results are for the same predictor.

```
`data$Grain<- as.numeric(as.character(data$Grain))
result <- sapply(names(data)[1 : 4], 
             function(x) { 
               lapply(names(data)[1 : 4], 
                      function(y) {
                        if (x != y) {
                          model <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Grain", "~", "Age", "*", x)), data) 
                          return(list(x = x, 
                                      r.squared = summary(model)$r.squared, 
                                      coefficients =  summary(model)$coefficients))
                        }
                      })
             })`
```

I've tried removing `function(y){}` and `if(x!=y{}`, but I get "Error: unexpected '}' in "}".

```
`result <- sapply(names(data)[1 : 4], 
             function(x) { 
               lapply(names(data)[1 : 4],
                          model <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Grain", "~", "Age", "*", x)), data) 
                          return(list(x = x, 
                                      r.squared = summary(model)$r.squared, 
                                      coefficients =  summary(model)$coefficients))
                      )
             })`
```

Perhaps a more promising solution is using lapply to generate a list of regressions:

`reg <- lapply(data[,-c(1:5,8,18)], function(x) summary(lm(data$Grain~ data$Age*x)))`

The problem with that is that I can only print all 150 summaries at once- I haven't figured out how to store at least the P values and hopefully also R squared values in a data frame. It's ok if the P values and R squared values are in different data frames. I need to make a presentation on how these 150 predictors are related to Grain and Age, and I don't think a screenshot of 150 different summary print outs is ideal. Thanks for reading- I did my best to check for duplicates but if there's a post you think I missed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `update` to add the "predictor" to a base formula `fo`. However, your dependent variable is a factor (i.e. a categorical variable) ant your should think about your method again. Also variable `Key` is a factor with 3999 levels and interaction analysis might run forever.

Anyway, I transform `Grain` into numeric and show you how to work with `update`. I include just the numeric variables into the process (by excluding `is.factor`).

The `r.squared` we can best store as an attribute, since it doesn't fit well into the coefficients table.

```
data <- read.csv("X:/Downloads/grain yield by environment long.csv", stringsAsFactors=T)
## transform Grain to numeric
data <- transform(data, Grain=as.numeric(levels(Grain))[Grain])

## names vector of independent (numeric) variables
nm <- names(data[!sapply(data, is.factor)])  

## base formula
fo <- Grain ~ Age 

## try out what `update` does
x <- "LAT"
update(fo, paste(". ~ . *", x))
# Grain ~ Age + LAT + Age:LAT

## using `update` in a small `sapply`
res <- sapply(nm, function(x){
  smy <- summary(lm(update(fo, paste(". ~ . *", x)), data))
  `attr<-`(smy$coef, "r.squared", smy$r.squared)
})
```

### Result

```
length(res)
# [1] 138

head(res, 3)
# $LAT
#               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) -203.80608 247.042950 -0.8249824 4.094316e-01
# Age          444.71213 115.503286  3.8502119 1.198906e-04
# LAT           21.48553   5.342822  4.0213824 5.894224e-05
# Age:LAT      -14.29534   2.502305 -5.7128675 1.193053e-08
# attr(,"r.squared")
# [1] 0.3360184
# 
# $ID
#               Estimate Std. Error    t value      Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  798.15199  14.943853  53.410054  0.000000e+00
# Age         -214.49895   7.897641 -27.159875 4.876711e-149
# ID          -144.12033  81.112221  -1.776802  7.567810e-02
# Age:ID        41.77544  31.049721   1.345437  1.785617e-01
# attr(,"r.squared")
# [1] 0.3293592
# 
# $Latitude
#                Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  -204.04718 247.054540 -0.8259196 4.088998e-01
# Age           444.85794 115.509219  3.8512765 1.193725e-04
# Latitude       21.49072   5.343065  4.0221707 5.874607e-05
# Age:Latitude  -14.29847   2.502429 -5.7138368 1.186329e-08
# attr(,"r.squared")
# [1] 0.3360205
```

To access the `r.squared` from the attributes of a specific list element you may do, e.g. for `LAT`:

```
attr(res$LAT, "r.squared")
# [1] 0.3360184
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but when I try to define "res" I get the error `Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 2 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned`

Comment: @ginger_cat You need to exclude `"Gear"` from the names vector `nm` which we use for the right-hand-side of the `fo`rmula, because it is your independent variable (left-hand-side). In my code this happened by accident, since I've excluded it by excluding the `is.factor` variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to generate three separate tables- one for P values, one for R-squared values, and one for slope coefficients. For some reason they weren't the same length, so I couldn't cbind them into one table, but this is 95% of what I was after. I'm new at this so I'm open to suggestions on how to make this more elegant and/or robust- I'll have to do it again on a data frame with 500 columns.

```
data$Grain<- as.numeric(as.character(data$Grain)) #This should be numeric

ls1 <- list()
ls2 <- list()
ls3 <- list()
ls4 <- list()
ls5 <- list()
data2 <- data[-c(1:5,9:15)] #removing non-data rows such as Key, ID, Experiment, etc

for (i in names(data2)){ 
  model <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Grain", "~", "Age", "*", i)), data2)
  pval <- summary(model)$coefficients[,4] #extracts P values for model
  rsq <- summary(model)$r.squared
  slope <- summary(model)$coefficients[,1] #extracts slope coefficients for model
  ls1 <- c(ls1, pval[3]) #extracts P values of third row, which is the predictor i
  ls2 <- c(ls2, pval[4]) #extracts P values of fourth row, which is interaction of predictor i and Age
  ls3 <- c(ls3, rsq)
  ls4 <- c(ls4, slope[3]) #extracts slope of third row, which is the predictor i
  ls5 <- c(ls5, slope[4]) #extracts slope of fourth row, which is interaction of predictor i and Age
}


col1 <- do.call(rbind, ls1) #this puts the list into one column, for easier viewing
col2 <- do.call(rbind, ls2)
Rs <- do.call(rbind, ls3)
col4 <- do.call(rbind, ls4)
col5 <- do.call(rbind, ls5)
Pvalues <- cbind(col1,col2)
slopes <- cbind(col4,col5)

write.csv(Pvalues, file = "C:/Users/.../Pvalues.long.csv", row.names = TRUE)
write.csv(slopes, file = "C:/Users/.../slopes.long.csv", row.names = TRUE)
write.csv(Rs, file = "C:/Users/.../Rs.long.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Now I can easily scan these documents to see which predictors are significant, how much variance they explain, and in what direction and to what degree they affect the response variable.

Comment: I'm getting a message `Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  problem with term 2 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned` but the output is as expected so I'm going ahead with this solution. Any insights into this warning would be appreciated.